# Zsh COLUMNS set too narrow for proportional width font

Tags: fonts, terminal, zsh

I'm trying out a proportional font in a terminal, thanks to [mlterm](http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/), which seems to be the only true terminal [capable of proportional](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/588/can-i-use-a-non-monospaced-font-in-either-vim-or-gvim).  (I do actually use Emacs, which can handle proportional, but `multi-term` et al aren't working well with such font tweaks.)  Not sure I'll love proportional, but do want to give it a fair try for some shell things.

One nice thing about proportional is that it's generally narrower.  But this is confusing Zsh, which seems to set `COLUMNS` based on a monospace width calculation, as shown below.  Notice the very early line wrapping.

[image]

It might be sufficient to keep columns set to 2x (or maybe 1.8x) its normal calculation.  Anyone have an idea of how to do this?  Or how to just tell Zsh to not recompute so I could set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have a workaround specific to *mlterm*: Set the screen-font ratio to 50%.

[image: mlterm settings]

Comment: Any "workaround" would be terminal-specific, since it's impossible to have a perfect solution to irregular-sized characters on a regular grid.